# unkown characters on nfs shared directory

Tags: linux, windows, nfs

I have a raspberry pi that is used as an nfs server, and a windows computer that mount this shared directory.

Unforunately, files names inside shared directory on client side have unknown characters. I think issue comes from character encoding. Do you know how to set character encoding for nfs windows client ?

For example, the "Videos" directory on raspberry is displayed "VidÃ©os" on windows